# Curl Error 56 in PHP when sending Request Web Service

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I send a REQUEST through SOAP to a Web Service that has a self-signed certificate, for which I apply the following functions so that it is omitted

```
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
```

But I get the following error code:

```
CURL error: 56
```

Do some research and according to the Curl (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) error listing this is due to Failure with receiving network data.

What other function can I apply so that this error is overcome?

```
        $curl_options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>20

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding SOAPAction in my header:

```
$headers = array("Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", "Accept: text/xml", "SOAPAction: http://direccion.com/Crear", "Content-length: ".strlen($xml), );
```